# How to update cross object fields based on parent fields?

Tags: apex, trigger, case

My requirement is based on case reason picklist value on Case, which automatically updates a custom object picklist value.

I have wrote trigger, but it doesn't work properly

```
trigger updateCaseUser on Case (after insert, after update){

    List<ID> OppIds = New List<ID>();

    for(Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if(c.Reason == 'Other') {
          OppIds.add(c.Reason);
        }
    }

    List<CaseUser__c> cuser = [SELECT id, skill__c FROM CaseUser__c WHERE id in :OppIds];

    for (integer i = 0 ; i < cuser.size(); i++) {
        cuser[i].skill__c = 'It Team';
     }

    update cuser;  
}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste your actual trigger?  This looks like pseudo code and is full of errors.... but just at first glance it looks like you're adding the text field value in to your OppIds list... you should be adding your CaseUser__c ID to that list.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to be more specific than "its not working"?

Answer (score 1):

> Trigger is supposed to not working because of following reasons:

1. You have added Case reasons into OppIds which is `List<ID>`.
2. Those ids are being fed into SOQL where `id in :OppIds`.

Naturally, those values will not match to return any results.

**Suggestions**

Your requirements can be achieved through process builder.

Either way, if you need to perform through trigger, it will be like this:

```
trigger updateCaseUser on Case (after insert, after update){

    List<ID> OppIds = New List<ID>();

    for(Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if(c.Reason == 'Other') {
          OppIds.add(c.Id); //add case ids.
        }
    }

    //based on caseIds retrieve related CaseUsers whose skills needs to be updated.
    List<CaseUser__c> cuser = [SELECT id, skill__c FROM CaseUser__c WHERE Caseid in :OppIds];

    for (integer i = 0 ; i < cuser.size(); i++) {
        cuser[i].skill__c = 'It Team';
     }

    update cuser;  
}
```

Comment: caseid field not available in CaseUser__c error occured

Comment: Then, how are you relating Cases with CaseUser__c? I thought it should be related